# Daisy chained Dell P2419HC monitors fonts are blurry but video and pictures appear fine

Tags: windows-10, display, multiple-monitors, fonts, external-display

I have got two Dell P2419HC daisy chained to my laptop. The connections are as following

Laptop to 1st Monitor -> usb-c

1st Monitor to 2nd Monitor -> DP 1.2 cable.

Images and videos are fine but font in browsers and apps is blurry. I have tried changing cleartype font settings, display settings but it doesn't work. Changing monitor brightness, sharpness or other settings doesn't help as well.

I am attaching two images. First one is captured while text is magnified using windows magnifier and second is from youtube with normal zoom.

[image: magnifier screenshot]

[image: normal screenshot]

Not sure what I am doing wrong. Any help on this will be great.

Comment: What are the display scaling settings for the different monitors? Which is the primary display? Have you tried logging out then logging back in yet?

Comment: I had the time now to check your screenshots on a PC display. The bad font rendering in the first screenshot is most likely the result of the Magnifier scaling algorithm. It cannot be used to diagnose the problem. The second screenshot looks normal, except font smoothing is not using RGB subpixel rendering.

Comment: Both monitors resolution is 1920x1080(recommended) and scaling is 100%(recommended). I tried googling it but couldn't find a way to go for RGB subpixel rendering. Is there a way we can do it in Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

If it's visible on screenshots, then it has nothing to do with displays. Screenshots show what the GPU renders, not what the displays display, so if your screenshots show the problem, then it's already there before pixels go to the display.

Try adjusting your ClearType settings. Searching *ClearType* in the Start menu should get you to the right settings page. A wizard will ask you a couple questions about your preferences and adjust don't smoothing settings accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation on fonts and display. This clears out the display. I have tinkered plenty with cleartype settings but still fonts are blurry. Is there any other setting I should be changing.